# Continue recording an audio after interrupting by phone call, AVAudioRecorder

Tags: swift, audio-recording, avaudiorecorder

How to continue recording an audio after interrupting by incoming phone call? Now after incoming call my record stops, but I want to able to resume recording

```
func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(_ recorder: AVAudioRecorder,
                                     successfully flag: Bool) {

    if flag {
        recorder.stop()
        isRecording = false
        recordButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "RecButtonRecord"), for: .normal)
        playButton.isEnabled = true
        playButton.alpha = 1
        titleRecordTextView.isHidden = false
        sourceRecordTextView.isHidden = false

    }
    else {

      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
recorder.pause()
```

To **pause** the `recording` and  You've to check this

Manage from **AppDelegate** method which is

```
 func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }
```

, you have to **resume** from here with use of `NotificationCenter`.

Comment: Yes, I know it, but where I should add this? In what func?

Comment: Thanx for answer, do you know any examples how exactly to do it

Comment: You was wrong, I should use `applicationWillResignActive` instead `applicationWillEnterForeground `